python: NameError: name 'first' is not defined when I import the whole package
When I import the whole package, it gives me a NameError. But when I import individual modules and run the same code, it executes properly.
My structure is:

my_package/directory

__init__.py
first.py
second.py
main.py



When I run main.py as below, it gives me a NameError:
import my_package
first.say_1st()
second.say_2nd()

"C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\python.exe" "D:\\E Drive\\Training\\pythonProject1\\Sample scripts\\Package example\\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\E Drive\\Training\\pythonProject1\\Sample scripts\\Package example\\main.py", line 4, in \<module\>
first.say_1st()
^^^^^
NameError: name 'first' is not defined. Did you mean: 'list'?

Process finished with exit code 1

But when I run main.py as below, it gives me the expected output.
from my_package import first
first.say_1st()

from my_package import second
second.say_2nd()

Am I doing something wrong?

You are doing it right in the second snippet of code.

Thanks quamrana for the response. But shudn't it work for the 1st snippet as well? I am just trying to figure out. Forgive my ignorance

I tried this :-
import my_package
#from my_package import *
#from my_package import first
my_package.first.say_1st()
#from my_package import second
my_package.second.say_2nd()
It's giving me this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\E Drive\Training\pythonProject1\Sample scripts\Package example\main.py", line 5, in 
my_package.first.say_1st()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'my_package' has no attribute 'first'

To install all packages, use from my_package import * instead of just import my_package. I have seen this issue before, and all I can say is Python is a bit funky.
Hopefully this fixes your issue.

While this works it is not recommended since you will not be able to trace where an import comes from anymore.
